# Closed :Android: App keeps crashing when using com.google.android.material below android 9 (sdk 29)

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, androidx, material-components-android

My app keeps crashing when running material.io components below sdk 29. Im using app theme as "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar" also

Build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.marketapplication"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {

      implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
//implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:android-otpview-pinview:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

logcat

com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
at com.example.marketapplication.activity.LoginMainActivity.onCreate(LoginMainActivity.kt:31)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:243)
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:217)
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:145)
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:115)
at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:460)
at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:419)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
at com.example.marketapplication.activity.LoginMainActivity.onCreate(LoginMainActivity.kt:31) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: show error log please

Comment: Added. Please check!

Comment: Show your style.xml

Comment: I have 2 style.xml in my project and im changing values inside styles.xml(v21) and did not change inside my styles.xml. So yes im dumb @IntelliJAmiya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem related to `SDK Versions`, rather you are using a Widget `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` which is a Component of `Theme.Material Components`.

That is what the first line of the stacktrace tells you `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`,

And down at some line, it says: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style of this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).` which is complaining about some kind of `Theme` incompatibility.

In Short, Try changing The app Theme to `Theme.MaterialComponents` in **res/styles** or avoid using its components like `TextInputLayout`

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too.

Just go to res/styles.xml and change the AppTheme (or whatever your application theme is called), and change its parent to Theme.MaterialComponents.* and you're good to go

EDIT: if you are already using it, you might need to do a clean and rebuild of your project after doing the change

Comment: Im really dumb. I have 2 style.xml in my project and im changing values inside styles.xml(v21) and did not change inside my styles.xml. 
Thank you!